# Unable to generate Excel File

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an working code which is merging multiple CSV files and generating excel out of it .
The code is working fine in windows but in Unix it's not creating any excel file ...

```
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter('default.xlsx')
 for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
     df = pd.read_csv(file)
     print(os.path.splitext(file)[0])
     df.to_excel(writer , sheet_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0])
     print ("Writing to Excel....")
```

The output I am getting like below but it's not generating excel file . Using python 2.7

```
Main
Writing to Excel....
Source
Writing to Excel....
Target
Writing to Excel....
Filter
Writing to Excel....
Router
Writing to Excel....
Joiner
Writing to Excel....
Aggregate
Writing to Excel....
Expression
Writing to Excel....
Incoming Fields
Writing to Excel....
Target Field Mapping
Writing to Excel....
Transformation Lineage
Writing to Excel....
Ports Rename Details
Writing to Excel....
```

Comment: What did you claim for `writer`?

Comment: edit the question

Comment: Did you save and close `writer`?

Comment: Thanks , that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add

```
 writer.save()
```

Complete code -

```
import glob, os
os.chdir(r"C:\TEMP\Output")
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=os.path.splitext(file)[0])
    print(os.path.splitext(file)[0]) 
 writer.save()
```